# How to generate convex hull from points with "relaxation"

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

Using `R` and the simple features package `sf`,  I can generate a convex hull polygon from a `MULTIPOINT` using `st_convex_hull`. I'd like to do something a little more involved with "relaxation" or a certain degree concave as seen in this image.

[image]

Is this possible with some combinations of `sf` operations? Any guidance on where to begin with this?

Comment: Have you tried first creating a buffer, e.g. with `st_buffer` at some distance from the points, then getting the convex hull?

Comment: Buffer areas 3 and 2 above are never going to be coming from a "convex hull" procedure. They could be from "Concave Hull" or "Alpha Shape" functions. Search for those - R functions exist.